# Inconsistent data when traversing through 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

I have 4 tables (with a lot of fields, but only a few important ones in each) that I'm working with.

1. Customer table
2. Inventory table
3. Invoice table
4. Invoice details table

What I've been doing is getting a customer or item's id.

If it's a customer, I take their id to get their information from the customer table. Now, in order to get the item's they carry I have to look at each invoice with that customer's id. So I grab all of those. Each invoice has and id that links to an invoice detail table, so I take that invoice id and grab the invoice details that match with the invoice. Then the items are in the iteminventory table, so I take the item id from the invoice detail and get all of the items for every invoice associated with that customer. Then I run that data through a loop to get rid of any empty values and pass the item array to the view.

Now if it's an item the actions are performed vice versa. I take the item, look at each invoice detail containing that wine, grab the invoice id from it, and grab the customer id from each invoice respectively.

Somehow I wind up with customer's carrying a product, but when I go to the product to see what customer's carry it, the previously mentioned customer won't be listed under the product.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most SQL programmers solve this kind of problem with a single query using a series of JOIN directives and an appropriate ORDER BY directive. They write a bit of php code to read the resultset row by row, detect rows in which the invoice id changes, and format the information appropriately.

It seems like a good idea for you to read up on how to use JOIN directives if you don't already know.

Comment: I was able to get it. Thanks Ollie!